# Strange behaviour in OpenMP nested loop

Tags: nested, openmp

In the following program I get different results (serial vs OpenMP), what is the reason? At the moment I can only think that perhaps the loop is too "large" for the threads and perhaps I should write it in some other way but I am not sure, any hints?

Compilation: `g++-4.2 -fopenmp main.c functions.c -o main_elec_gcc.exe`

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <omp.h>
    #include <math.h>

    #define NRACK 64
    #define NSTARS 1024

    double mysumallatomic_serial(float rocks[NRACK][3],float moon[NSTARS][3],float qr[NRACK],float ql[NSTARS]) {
        int j,i;
        float temp_div=0.,temp_sqrt=0.;
        float difx,dify,difz;
        float mod2x, mod2y, mod2z;
        double S2 = 0.;
    for(j=0; j<NRACK; j++){
        for(i=0; i<NSTARS;i++){     
            difx=rocks[j][0]-moon[i][0];
            dify=rocks[j][1]-moon[i][1];
            difz=rocks[j][2]-moon[i][2];
            mod2x=difx*difx;
            mod2y=dify*dify;
            mod2z=difz*difz;
            temp_sqrt=sqrt(mod2x+mod2y+mod2z);
            temp_div=1/temp_sqrt;
            S2 += ql[i]*temp_div*qr[j];     
        }
    }
    return S2;
}

double mysumallatomic(float rocks[NRACK][3],float moon[NSTARS][3],float qr[NRACK],float ql[NSTARS]) {
    float temp_div=0.,temp_sqrt=0.;
    float difx,dify,difz;
    float mod2x, mod2y, mod2z;
    double S2 = 0.;

#pragma omp parallel for shared(S2)
    for(int j=0; j<NRACK; j++){
        for(int i=0; i<NSTARS;i++){
            difx=rocks[j][0]-moon[i][0];
            dify=rocks[j][1]-moon[i][1];
            difz=rocks[j][2]-moon[i][2];
            mod2x=difx*difx;
            mod2y=dify*dify;
            mod2z=difz*difz;
            temp_sqrt=sqrt(mod2x+mod2y+mod2z);
            temp_div=1/temp_sqrt;
            float myterm=ql[i]*temp_div*qr[j];  
            #pragma omp atomic
            S2 += myterm;
        }
    }
    return S2;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
float rocks[NRACK][3], moon[NSTARS][3];
float qr[NRACK], ql[NSTARS];
int i,j;

for(j=0;j<NRACK;j++){
    rocks[j][0]=j;
    rocks[j][1]=j+1;
    rocks[j][2]=j+2;
    qr[j] = j*1e-4+1e-3;
    //qr[j] = 1;
}

for(i=0;i<NSTARS;i++){
    moon[i][0]=12000+i;
    moon[i][1]=12000+i+1;
    moon[i][2]=12000+i+2;
    ql[i] = i*1e-3 +1e-2 ;
    //ql[i] = 1 ;
}
printf(" serial: %f\n", mysumallatomic_serial(rocks,moon,qr,ql));
printf(" openmp: %f\n", mysumallatomic(rocks,moon,qr,ql));
return(0);

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `reduction` instead of shared variable and remove `#pragma omp atomic`, like:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:S2)
```

And it should work faster, because there are no need for atomic operations which are quite painful in terms of performance and threads synchronization.

**UPDATE**

You can also have some difference in results because of the operations order:

`\sum_1^100(x[i]) != \sum_1^50(x[i]) + \sum_51^100(x[i])`

Comment: Try to define your arrays as shared

Comment: BTW, why did you copy your function? It should work fine if you compile it without openmp. And I think it is better to compare results for the same code with and without `-fopenmp` switch.

Comment: and what is the difference in your results?

Comment: the results tend to be around 5% different. BTW I do not understand what you mean with the summatoria: a + b + c + d = (a + b) + (c + d)

Comment: Yup, this is what I meant. More detailed example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749493/strange-float-behaviour-in-openmp
Try to use `double` for more accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You have data races on most of the temporary variables you are using in the parallel region - difx, dify, difz, mod2x, mod2y, mod2z, temp_sqrt, and temp_div should all be private.  You should make these variables private by using a private clause on the parallel for directive.

Comment: As far as I remember all variables are private by default in C++

Comment: yes, now it works. But i also can see that I lose a lot of performance, openmp version is 0.5 times faster

Comment: @Werner because your loops are quite small. Could you update your code please?

Comment: what do you mean with that "the loops are quite small"?. thanks

Comment: By default in OpenMP, most variables are shared.  There are exceptions and they are listed, so you have to be careful.

Comment: The loops are small (i.e., the number of iterations is small), which means that the amount of work given to each thread is relatively small.  The timings I made from this code show that running it in serial mode is always faster.  In any case, you could also try using reduction instead of atomic.  My runs for a small number of threads (in the 2-6 range, which gives each thread more work) shows reduction being twice as fast as atomic.  Please note though, this is very dependent on the implementation of atomic and reduction.